# How to resolve string[DT_STR] error in csv file import

Tags: sql-server, csv, sybase

I exported a table and also its data from Sybase DB in csv file. Then I intend to import it into MSSQL Server using SSMS 18.

I created the table in MSSQL Server retaining the same data types as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee_account](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [debit_acct_no] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [create_dt] [datetime] NULL,
    [created_by] [varchar](45) NULL,
    [Limit] [numeric](26, 6) NOT NULL,
    [allow_od] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [allow_bal_enq] [char](1) NULL,
    [scheme_type] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then I followed this step:

Right click on DB -> Click Task -> Import Data -> Next -> Select Flat File as Data Source -> and so on ..

It flags on the columns that are not string (Varchar, char), and the import from the CSV file failed.

[image: csv issue]

Sample data:

```
UserID,debit_acct_no,active,create_dt,created_by,Limit,allow_od,allow_bal_enq,scheme_type
1,9876765432,1,20/03/2017 7:55:47.396,HAMIT LAMIL,13388.330000,N,,
1,2345654362,1,20/03/2017 7:56:01.120,HAMIT LAMIL,17715.330000,N,,
1,8797654324,1,20/03/2017 7:56:04.663,HAMIT LAMIL,88185.880000,N,,
```

I don't want to convert all the other columns to varchar.

Even when I uncheck the covert, the issue still remain.

Finally, I did this, but issue not resolved for the create_dt.

[image: date_format]

When I completed the process, I got this error:

```
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "create_dt" (22) to column "create_dt" (88).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[create_dt]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[create_dt]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (72) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (73). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0209017: Data Flow Task 1: Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

How do I resolve this and resolve the issue?

Comment: *"and the import from the CSV file failed."* And what was the failure reason? You've provided no sample data here, so we have no idea why it failed.

Comment: @ThomA - I've updated the code with the error

Comment: You're getting conversion errors. As this appears to be on a date column it appears that your dates are in an ambiguous format, and so can't be parsed, or they are invalid values. With no sample data, I can't comment more on *why* the format you've chosen to use is a problem. If you can't address the extract to use an unambiguous format, then you'll need to either import to SSIS as a string and use a derived column transformation to convert the value to a date (and time) data type or import to a staging table and then convert the value when you insert it into the production table.

Comment: @ThomA - Sorry, I've updated the code with sample data.

Comment: This import "wizard" is such a joke. if you want to save your sanity, only import into text columns and them do a proper conversion manually

Comment: @siggemannen - I imported into varchar column. When after the import, I tried to convert the varchar back to datetime, it becomes impossible

Comment: well, the date format you use is not standard. you can do something like: select convert(datetime, '20/03/2017 7:56:04.663', 103)

Comment: Not a great datetime format to start with. Was the time component of it meant to be `AM` or `PM`? Really you want to use unambiguous datetime formats that won't be affected by regional settings on your computer, nor by `SET DATEFORMAT` inside SQL Server, so something like `2017-03-20T07:56:04.663` (for AM) or `2017-03-20T19:56:04.663` (for PM) would be ideal.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - That is how the record came from the source and I don't have control over that. Kindly assist on how to import the record from my side in MSSQL Server

Comment: Do you even know if the times are AM or PM? Just import the file into a staging table with all-character columns and merge it from there.

Answer (score 0):

source typpe: you choose Unicode string [DT_WSTR]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).